# how to assign a function's expression to a variable in smarty

Tags: prestashop, smarty

say I've got a text like this:

```
{l s='Total'}
```

'l' is a function. The string 'Total' in fact will be a translation: 'l' will output that. I would need to assign the resulting translation to another smarty variable. Is it possible and how to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `assign var`

```
{assign var='translatedString' value={l s='Total'}}
```

And then somewhere else in the template file to output it.

```
{$translatedString}
```

Or with `capture`

```
{capture name=translatedString}
    {l s='Total'}
{/capture}
```

And output with

```
{$smarty.capture.translatedString}
```

You could also assign capture to a var

```
{assign var='capturedVar' value=$smarty.capture.translatedString}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could use a smarty tag inside a smarty tag (value={l s='Total'}} ). Great :)